# Dynamically add an attribute to elements that frequently get AJAX'd on and off the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, tooltip

I am using several Telerik ASP MVC grids that frequently AJAX a SQL db for rows of data.  Initially, when the page first loads, these grids are empty.  When data binding finishes, four types of buttons appear.  I want to add a tooltip to them.  I'm using the following script for the OnDataBound action:

```
function addToolTips() {
    // jquery to add hover tooltips to elements
        $(".t-edit").attr("title", "Edit this record.");
        $(".t-delete").attr("title", "Delete this record.");
        $(".t-update").attr("title", "Save changes.");
        $(".t-cancel").attr("title", "Cancel changes.");
}
```

The problem is: It's not checking whether or not it has the attribute yet.  There are several thousand of these on the page across several grids.  And not all of them will have the data-binding activity at once.

I've attached `addToolTips()` to the OnDataBound action to *all* the grids (I think there are 8).

```
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("InvoiceGrid_onDataBinding")
                            .OnDataBound("InvoiceGrid_onDataBound"))

function InflowsGrid_onDataBound() {
    $("#InflowGrid").unblock();
    addToolTips();
}
```

Before Data Bound:
[image: img]

End result:

[image: end result]

Comment: What's the question exactly? Is it "how do I avoid adding tooltips to thousands of elements unnecessarily?"?

Comment: That's correct.  If one grid gets DataBound action, it calls the tooltip function for all grids.  This is unnecessary.

Comment: If the 'x' icon and 'pencil' icon do not exist after the ajax call, how is the tool tip attaching to them?

Comment: Can you show a picture of what it should NOT look like?

Comment: You misunderstand.  Before databind: http://i50.tinypic.com/iel8b4.png Empty grids.

Tooltip action is attached to "On Data Bound" (finished) action.